# Streaming Google Cloud Monitoring alerts into Twitter

Tags: twitter, cloud, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

so we previously were able to send Nagios notifications into Twitter. We have since switched to Google Stackdriver, and would like to create an alert notification channel for Twitter. I had a look at both Google Cloud Monitoring API and Twitter API, but I don't think we can do this yet. Has anyone successfully done this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately currently there is no support for Twitter, however it supports this Notifications Channels [1]: Email, Mobile App, PagerDuty, SMS, Slack, Webhooks and Pub/Sub.

There is a Feature Request in their Public Issue Tracker[2] asking for this characteristic on Notifications Channels, and you will be able to follow any progress by Clicking in the “Star” icon, at the top-left of the Feature Request.

__

[1]https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels
[2]issuetracker.google.com/172456245

Comment: Hey @agmance thanks so much for that info. I am now following the feature request.